# Keras Tokenizer.texts_to_sequences returning an list of lists instead of a np.array

Tags: python, numpy, keras, lstm

I am working on building a sentiment classifier for the IMDB movie review dataset and using an LSTM layer with Keras.
The problem is that I cannot get the correct type of Input for the Neural Network (aka. `numpy array`)

This is what I'm doing

```
xtrain,xtest,ytrain,ytest = model_selection.train_test_split(reviews,review_sent,test_size=0.2,stratify=review_sent)

t = Tokenizer(oov_token=0)

t.fit_on_texts(texts=xtrain)

train_seq = t.texts_to_sequences(xtrain)
test_seq = t.texts_to_sequences(xtest)

type(train_seq)
#returns 'list' of len(xtrain)
```

Where **reviews** are the strings of the reviews and **review_sent** a binary variable (the target)

Each element of the list is also a list, with the numerical sequence representing the review.
I am having a lot of trouble to transform this into an `np.array` so i can perform padding and end up with `xtrain_padded.shape = (n_train_samples, sequence_lenght)` so it can be the Input of a keras model.

If anyone can elaborate on how to do this, it would a really helpful.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Most likely your lists vary in length, so `numpy` cannot make a 2d array from the data.  It just returns a 1d array with references to those lists.

Comment: I am working on the padding also, but i'll keep in mind to do that before transforming to a 2d array. Thanks for the advice